# Time limit exceeded in binary search

Tags: c, gcc

I have been working on a program to search an element using binary search but every time i run this program i get a time limit exceeded error. Though i searched about this error but I am unable to find what is the error in this program pls help Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int BinarySearch(int low,int high,int *a,int item);
int main(){
  int a[50] , i , low , high , n , item , position;

  printf("Enter the number of Elements");
  scanf("%i",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%i",&a[i]);
  }

  printf("Enter the Element to be searched");
  scanf("%i",&item);
  low=0;
  high=n-1;
  position=BinarySearch(low,high,a,item);

  if(position==-1)
    printf("Item not found");
  else
    printf("item was found on the %i position",position);

  return 0;
}
int BinarySearch(int low,int high,int *a,int item){
  int mid,loc,flag=0;
  while (item!= a[mid] && low <= high)
  {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if(a[mid]==item){
      loc=mid;
      flag=flag+1;
    }
    else if (item < a[mid])
      high = mid - 1;
    else
      low = mid + 1;
  }
  if (flag>=1)
    return loc;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: you are using `mid` uninitialized in `BinarySearch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be multiple issues with your approach.

First, remove the semicolon next to your while, as it is now, your while is an **infinite loop** every time the searched item is not on **position 0**:

This:

```
while (item!= a[mid] && low <= high);
```

should become this:

```
while (item!= a[mid] && low <= high)
```

After you do that, please consider the following:

> Binary search can only be applied over a **sorted** collection.
>
> After reading all the numbers you should first sort them, then apply
>   your algorithm.

**EDIT**:

Also, as mentioned in the comment, you are trying to initialize some variables to 0 (zero) at the beginning of your function, but that is not quite right:

this:

```
int mid,loc,flag=0;
```

will only initialize **flag** to zero, **mid** and **loc** will be uninitialized, potential garbage.

Instead, do this:

```
int mid= (low + high) /2, loc=-1, flag=0;
```

By setting **loc** to **-1** you could even improve your code, by getting rid of the flag:

```
int BinarySearch(int low,int high,int *a,int item)
{
  int mid= (low + high) /2, loc=-1;
  while (item!= a[mid] && low <= high)
  {
    if(a[mid]==item){
      loc=mid;
    }
    else if (item < a[mid])
      high = mid - 1; 
    else
      low = mid + 1;
  }
  return loc;
}
```

As you can see, **flag** has been eliminated entirely and you don't need to set **mid** again.

Comment: Suggest `int mid = (low + high) / 2;` rather than `int mid=0`.

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad :) did not pay attention

Comment: I have edited to include a broader refactoring of the code at hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (item!= a[mid] && low <= high);
```

Remove the semi colon at the end :)

And your array must be sorted for binary search to work